# Check constraint to make sure values in a character column are all digits

Tags: sql, sybase

This is similar to [CHECK CONSTRAINT of string to contain only digits. (Oracle SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167767/check-constraint-of-string-to-contain-only-digits-oracle-sql) but I want to do this for Sybase.

I have a character column 'colExp' (8 characters). I want to put a check constraint to make sure values for this column are all digits.

How can I do this? This will work but its not elegant

```
colExp LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: @Pradeep, just add _AND LEN(colExp)=8_ to get the length you want.  Also, why no up vote? you selected it as the correct answer?

Comment: I forgot to up vote; did it now. And thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hurts the brain, not NOT LIKE (not range) works.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'foo' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

SELECT 1 WHERE '123' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

SELECT 1 WHERE 'aa1' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

SELECT 1 WHERE '1bb' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

SELECT 1 WHERE NULL NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

SELECT 1 WHERE '   ' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

--FAIL. Need extra check. Perhaps NULLIF
SELECT 1 WHERE '' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Double negative and deals with any length

Comment: Why did you write Fail for the last case? it is working fine here :-)

Comment: well, actually question doesn't say anything about the length to always be 8 characters so I will take it as an accepted answer..

Comment: The fail is on SQL Server... not Sybase :-)