# Oracle SQL Developer Postal Code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am having a problem with a check constraint in Oracle SQL Developer with Oracle 11g Express Edition.

I want to check if my postal code which is stored as `CHAR` just contains numbers and no other signs.

Tried various possibilities but nothing worked...

```
PLZ VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL

ADD CONSTRAINT TC_PLZ CHECK (PLZ LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Thanks and best regards, 
Michael

Comment: See similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167767/check-constraint-of-string-to-contain-only-digits-oracle-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHECK CONSTRAINT of string to contain only digits. (Oracle SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167767/check-constraint-of-string-to-contain-only-digits-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 4):

Use `regexp_like()`:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT TC_PLZ CHECK ( regexp_like(PLZ, '^[0-9]{5}$') )
```

Oracle -- like most databases -- only supports the ANSI standard wildcards in `LIKE`.  These are `%` for zero or more characters and `_` for exactly one character.

Regular expressions are much more powerful (although generally slower).

This might be a bit more efficient:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT TC_PLZ CHECK (translate(PLZ, '0123456789', '000000000') = '00000')
```

although I would go with the regular expression for clarity.

Comment: Clarity is in the eye of the beholder. A lot of people - including many programmers - don't understand regex. So, despite having given a regex solution I would use the `translate()` solution in my data model

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried to work with RegExp but failed, maybe because of missing "$" i think... Your solution worked immediately :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regular expression patterns you need to use a regex function in the CHECK constraint. This will work:

```
create table t23 (

PLZ VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT TC_PLZ CHECK (regexp_LIKE(plz, '^[0-9]{5}$'))
);
```

Although there's no need for regex; here's an alternative implementation:

```
create table t42 (

PLZ NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT T42_PLZ CHECK (length(plz)=5)
);
```

It's good practice to store numeric values using the correct datatype.

Check out [this LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fx69xk0f4ocw8tmipma5owrwm).

---

As @MT0 points out, the numeric implementation is not correct if a valid value can start with a leading zero. My purist data modeller persona states that values which must be a fixed number of digits should start at `10000` (for five digit values). However, I must admit I know of one system that did permit leading zeroes in a "numeric" field; they compounded this by allowing variable level values, which meant code `0300` identified something different from `00300`. What larks!

Comment: Storing it as a `NUMBER` data type will not preserve leading zeroes so the user could enter `00001` which would be a valid string but the database would convert it to `1` which would then fail the check.